# Extract date from a column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How to extract date from a string like '2:24 PM 6-20-2021'?

For example, I have a column called Dates (datatype 'String') in the table like below -

```
Dates
2:24 PM 6-20-2021
10:24 PM 6-21-2021
```

The output should be

```
Dates
6-20-2021
6-21-2021
```

Comment: Look at this page: https://copycoding.com/d/cast-as-date-parse-date-syntax-in-google-bigquery

Comment: @James it gives an error saying failed to parse the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to extract **date** from a string?

If you want to extract date as a date type so you will be able then to use data functions - consider below

```
select dates, 
  date(parse_datetime('%H:%M %p %m-%d-%Y', dates)) date
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Meantime, if you want to extract data as a string (as it is in original string) - consider below

```
select dates, 
  split(dates, ' ')[offset(2)] date
from your_table
```

with output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is a 3rd element separated by space

```
select regrexp_substr ('10:24 PM 6-21-2021', '[^ ]+',1 ,3 ) from dual
```

explanation :

1. [^ ]  not space characters
2. +    one or more elements(not spaces as it is situated after [^ ])
3. 1     starting from first position
4. 3     is occurence

Answer (score 0):

Command

```
"select* from table where column == 'date' or column like %'date'%"
```

should work!

Comment: this returns no results