# How to extract date from a string type column in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69511414/extract-date-from-a-column) post but it doesn't seem to work for my specific case.

I have a column called FlightDate of type text in MySQL and the date format in it looks like this:

`7/25/2001 0:00`
`10/2/2000 0:00`

I want to do a group by on just the year. Can someone let me know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `group by year(column)` and see shat happens.

Comment: Not working :/.

Comment: What is your date columns data type?